# Linear Operators - Injectivity

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to understand this proof of the following Lemma, that I found in an article on Existence of Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors, but I don't understand the following step:

*Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional complex vector space, $v\in V$ and $c\gt 0$. Since for every $v\in V\setminus \{ 0 \}$ and $k\in\mathbb C$ we have $||T(v) - kv||\ge c||v||$, then for every $k\in\mathbb C$ the operator $T - kI$ is one-to-one.*

Why does this guarantee injectivity of $T-kI$?

Comment: $c>0$ is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to assume $c > 0$.  So assuming, we then have $\Vert (T - k I)(v) \Vert \ge c\Vert v \Vert > 0$ for $v \ne 0$.  Thus $(T - k I)v \ne 0$ for $v \ne 0$.  If now $T - kI$ were *not* injective, then there would exist *some* $w \in V$ and *distinct* $y_1, y _2 \in V$ with $(T - k I)y_1 = (T - k I)y_2 = w$.  But this implies $(T - k I)(y_1 - y_2)  = 0$; since as we have seen $y_1 - y_2 \ne 0$ implies $(T - k I)(y_1 - y_2) \ne 0$, we must thus have $y_1 - y_2 = 0$, contradicting the distinction of $y_1$, $y_2$.   Thus we must have $y_1 = y_2$ and so $T - k I$ is injective for every $k \in \Bbb C$.  ***QED.***

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as ever,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: In fact c > 0! Thanks a lot. Cheers

Comment: @Diogo Caetano:  my pleasure sir!

Answer (score 0):

$$T(v) - kv =0\implies 0=\|T(v) - kv\| \ge  c \|v\|\implies v=0.$$